# Как управлять громкостью звука windows 10 python?

Tags: аудио

Нужно управлять именно в общем системой, через стандартный микшер. Благодарю.
Хотелось бы устанавливать свое значение( с помощью ввода числа), прибавлять и убавлять по не многу,  выключать, устанавливать максимум и получать текущее значение

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448934/how-to-control-windows-master-audio-in-python-script

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать, используя модуль [Pycaw](https://pypi.org/project/pycaw/).

```
pip install pycaw
```

Из официальной документации:

```py
from ctypes import cast, POINTER
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume
    
devices = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
interface = devices.Activate(
    IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
volume = cast(interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))
    
print(volume.GetMute())
print(volume.GetMasterVolumeLevel())
print(volume.GetVolumeRange()) #
volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel(-20.0, None)
```